# Why are Angular directives considered classes and not functions?

Tags: angular, typescript

The way the Ng directives are used within HTML tags (view) makes them look like functions to be invoked upon rather than instances of a class. Or maybe they are static methods that can be invoked without a class instance.
Sorry I am coming from backend, OOP languages (C++, Python, Java, C#) and now working to learn Javascript and Typescript and sometimes the philosophy of web-dev is a different paradigm to me.

Comment: Both Java and C# use annotations or attributes to infer additional automatic functionality on classes and functions (see for example how both Java Spring and ASP.NET uses these constructs for route building in web applications).

Comment: Does it matter? I mean, they're attributes on elements in the DOM with or without values. They could be functions, classes, properties, whatever. The people who wrote Angular decided they should be classes. So they're classes.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Directives are classes that are decorated with the [`@Directive`](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#directive) decorator. Angular is as well a very Object Oriented Framework which suites devs coming from other OOP languages.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's true that classes are a template for creating objects. They encapsulate data with code to work on that data. But also - Decorators ***are*** the functions that modify JavaScript classes. Directives allow us to extend or manipulate the DOM. At the core, a directive is a function that executes whenever the Angular compiler finds it in the DOM.